# How to access map provider members in MappaJS

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

I cannot figure out how to access the map methods of the map provider.

Im using MaboxGL.

```
    mappa = new Mappa('MapboxGL', mappaKey);
    myMap = mappa.tileMap(options);
    this.myMap.map.isMoving(); //THIS LINE
```

In the documentation(https://mappa.js.org/docs/api-overlay.html) says "complete access to the base map library and its original properties and methods can be found in the map method. This allows to call any of the maps original properties or methods." but i cannot make it work.

Can anyone give me an advice on how to do it ?